# Spring-Hibernate Caching with Memcached

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, memcached

I have an application whose back end has been made with Spring and Hibernate.

I Want to apply memcaching to make the application more scalable. At first i thought that i could integrate the second level cache of hibernate with memcache but the problem arouse was that all the HQL written in the application r like book.grade.id where Book & Grade are two separate entities, hence, the second level cache mechanism failed.

Can anyone recommend me a way to implement caching? I have had a look at EHCache but i want the Memcache implementation for now. My application will be hit by several servers but only 1 Database Server will exist. Given the required conditions, any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Below  mentioned are the steps you can follow.

1. pom.xml changes to include the abstract cache mechanism for memcache and client implementation using  xmemcache.

   com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached
           spring-cache
           3.1.0

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.google.code.simple-spring-memcached</groupId>
       <artifactId>xmemcached-provider</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Note : You need to include cglib too as this is aop based.

1. configuration.xml file changes

```
   **defining beans**

    <bean name="cacheManager" class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCacheManager">
 <property name="caches">
     <set>
         <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.spring.SSMCache">
             <constructor-arg name="cache" index="0" ref="defaultCache"/>
             <!-- 5 minutes -->
             <constructor-arg name="expiration" index="1" value="300"/>
             <!-- @CacheEvict(..., "allEntries" = true) doesn't work -->
             <constructor-arg name="allowClear" index="2" value="false"/>
         </bean>
     </set>
 </property>

</bean>


<bean name="defaultCache" class="com.google.code.ssm.CacheFactory">
    <property name="cacheName" value="defaultCache" />
    <property name="cacheClientFactory">
        <bean name="cacheClientFactory"
            class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.xmemcached.MemcacheClientFactoryImpl" />
    </property>
    <property name="addressProvider">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.config.DefaultAddressProvider">
            <property name="address" value="x.x.x.x:11211" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="configuration">
        <bean class="com.google.code.ssm.providers.CacheConfiguration">
            <property name="consistentHashing" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>
```

1. Sample method...

   @Cacheable(value="defaultCache", key="new Integer(#id).toString().concat('.BOOKVO')")
       public BookVO getBookById(Integer id){

   ...
   }

with this changes your method will hit the db only if the key is not found in the memcache server.